# xampp-windows-x64-8.2.12-0-VS16-installer security issues

Tags: xampp, cve

I want to install XAMPP 8.2.12 on Windows, but passing the installer
xampp-windows-x64-8.2.12-0-VS16-installer.exe
to security scan many CVE were found (see attached image).
Are there known issues? Is there any package not affected?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xTYz.png)

passing the installer
xampp-windows-x64-8.2.12-0-VS16-installer.exe
to security scan many CVE were found (see attached image).
Are there known issues? Is there any package not affected?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xTYz.png)